# Why does the Bluetooth state automatically change when advertising and starting a Gatt server in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on One application that needs to Advertise itself and start a Gatt server at the same time. But somehow when I tried to do that device's Bluetooth state gets changed by itself.

I am unsing device
Samsung m32
Andriod 12

```
private val mBluetoothAdapterPowerStateReceiver: BroadcastReceiver =
        object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                val action = intent.action
                if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                    val state = intent.getIntExtra(
                        BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR
                    )
                    when (state) {
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> Log.d(TAG, "GantnerBLEAdapter: STATE_OFF")
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF -> Log.d(TAG, "GantnerBLEAdapter: STATE_TURNING_OFF")
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> Log.d(TAG, "GantnerBLEAdapter: STATE_ON")
                        BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON -> Log.d(TAG, "GantnerBLEAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is did register the callback for the same change

```
val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
 activity.registerReceiver(mBluetoothAdapterPowerStateReceiver, filter)
```

Here is my methods for advertising and Gatt server which are well palce in my onw Gattserver class.

```
fun startAdvertisementAndServer(){
        gantnerGattServer.startAdvertising()
        gantnerGattServer.startServer()
    }

    fun stopAdvertisementAndServer(){
        gantnerGattServer.stopServer()
        gantnerGattServer.stopAdvertising()
    }
```

I call startAdvertisementAndServer on a click of the button and also stop that stopAdvertisementAndServer if it is enbled.

If i do this start and stop multiple times more than twice Bluetooth state automatically started changing itself.

Android system automatically restarts the Bluetooth
So it called STATE_OFF and than STATE_ON.

Is this normal behaviour, i did check this in other apps it is not behaving same for other apps. do we need to do any extra code to prevent that?

Please help me in this.
I am using

```
minSdk 21
 targetSdk 33
```

Also gave all permission nessesary for BLUETOOTH

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

I did have findings for the same this is happening due to my advertisement data.

Which i pass as a scan response

```
val manufacturerDataKotlin = ByteArray(1)
        manufacturerDataKotlin[0] = 0x08

        manufacturerDataKotlin.plus(advInfo.toByteArray()).let {
            Log.d(TAG, "initializeAdvertiser: $it")
            mScanResponseData = AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .addManufacturerData(0x0403, it)
                .build()
        }
```

Passing as a scan response

```
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser!!.startAdvertising(
            mAdvertiseSettings,
            mAdvertiseData, mScanResponseData, mAdvertisingCallback
```

Am I doing something wrong here can the scan response affect the Bluetooth State?
)